# how to save binarystream as a media file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have binary asd i want to save as a myvideo.mp4, So *my question* is that if you have binary and you want to store your file,

So how it would accomplished any one idea i didn't work yet with binary and streaming i am new with these all things so if any one know please share a piece of example which solve my problem.

like response.outStream in this i am getting binary so can i save as a myvideo.mp4 what would be that process actually this binary is generating for mp4 conversion so any idea.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a FileStream to write to and then you will read the source stream in a loop, reading a block and then writing that block to the FileStream.  It should be fairly easy to find an example of reading a stream in a loop using its Read method.

Comment: thnx ok u want this type of thing exactly

Comment: string fileName = @"C:\Temp.data";
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName + " already exists!");
                return;
            }
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
            // Create the writer for data.
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            // Write data to Test.data.
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                w.Write((int)i);
            }
            w.Close();
            fs.Close();

Comment: Not a for loop.

`var buffer = new byte[1024];
int byteCount;

while ((byteCount = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    destinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
}`